# PHP and DOMDocument - loadHTML makes text disapear after the < sign

Tags: php, html, xml, domdocument

I have this html in a string:

```
$html = '<obj><p>Figure 1. different (<italic>p</italic>< 0.05).</p></obj>';
```

Then, I am loading this in a domDocument:

```
$doc  = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

Then, when I am dumping the content of the domDocument:

```
var_dump($doc->saveHTML());
```

I am getting:

```
<html><body><obj><p>Figure 1. different (<italic>p</italic></p></obj></body></html>
```

So th sign < and the rest disappeared.

Any idea why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print as xml

```
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
$html = '<obj><p>Figure 1. different (<italic>p</italic>'.    htmlspecialchars('< 0.05).') .'</p></obj>';

// Or else if you need this, then uncomment below line

//$html = htmlspecialchars('<obj><p>Figure 1. different (<italic>p</italic>< 0.05).</p></obj>');
$doc  = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
echo ($doc->saveHTML());
```

Comment: Thank you, but where dissapeared the < sign ?

Comment: thanks, but this will not really help me. The problem is that my html sting can var, so I don't know where the < sign is, or if there is any.

Comment: If you write,  htmlspecialchars('<obj><p>Figure 1. different (<italic>p</italic>< 0.05).</p></obj>');    then it will print whole html as it is.

Comment: Hmm, no, then i will lose my htnl tags, instead of having them as <i> I will have &lt;i&gt;

Answer (score 1):

The parser thinks you are opening a new HTML tag. Try using `&lt;` instead.

```
$html = '<obj><p>Figure 1. different (<italic>p</italic>&lt; 0.05).</p></obj>';
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to convert only the < that is the inferior sign, not the < from the italic tag ? This should be a general method

Comment: You are mixing up markup language (html) with content. If you only have content, you could use `htmlspecialchars()`. It's more of a practical inconvenience. You could also do something like this:

`$html = '<obj><p>Figure 1. different (<italic>p</italic>' . htmlspecialchars("< 0.05).") . '</p></obj>';`

Answer (score 1):

Well, that `<` is used by the html markup, thus the html string you post is interpreted by browsers as html.

If you want to show the *literal* html markup, you will have to escape it or mark it as preformatted text in an explicit manner: :

```
echo "<pre>\n";
var_dump($doc->saveHTML());
echo </pre\n";
```

If you want the html markup to be interpreted, but just have single characters escaped, you have to do that in an explicit manner, so that the browser can tell the difference:

```
$html = '<obj><p>Figure 1. different (<italic>p</italic>&lt; 0.05).</p></obj>';
var_dump($html);
```

Comment: Thank you @arkascha, but how to convert only those characters that are not html tags, for example if i use htmlspecialchars(), it will also convert the < and > from the italic etc...

Comment: Yes, that is true. The reason is the same why the browser cannot make a difference. There is no difference to tell them apart. The mistake has been done before: when constructing the string which mixes html markup and "reserved" characters. Those characters (the `<` here) should have been escaped when being inserted into a markup string. Now you have an "invalid" string. Typically such strings are build using sprintf constructs or similar. That is where escaping should take place: escape everything _not_ being part of the markup (not only single characters).